# Table structure for Messages System

Tags: sql, sql-server, message

Hi i need to design a messaging system like facebook. I was thinking to build table similar
[image]
<sub>(source: [serviciipeweb.ro](http://msprogrammer.serviciipeweb.ro/wp-content/uploads/MVC-4_94F/image.png))</sub>

where i can store olderMessage in another table so i can make quicker query in Message Main table...
but i cant resolve the problem about deleting messaging. If a user delete a message the other one should still read it.
How can i build it? 
I googled but i didnt find anything.

P.S: I must use `SQL-SERVER`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create two fields in your `Message` table:

1. DeletedByFrom
2. DeletedByTo

Filter your results on this:

```
where DeletedByFrom = False
```

So you only get the rows that weren't deleted (in this case by the 'From' user)